# Display from two column ComboBox

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a lastName, firstName sorted ComboBox. After having made a selection from this ComboBox only lastName is displayed. But I need both lastName AND firstName being displayed.
What settings do I have to set in order to display both values?

Comment: This is vague, what language?

Comment: @Mastro Access 2010!

Comment: Set a calculated column as the first column in your combo box. The _RowSource_ will be something like `SELECT lastName + ', ' + firstName FROM Table1 ORDER BY lastName, firstName`

Answer (score 1):

On combobox properties:

- set "Column Count" to 3
- set "Column Widths" to 0;0;1
- set your "Row Source" to get 3 columns, for example query: 
  `SELECT LastName,FirstName,FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FirstAndLastName FROM Table1 ORDER BY LastName,FirstName`

Comment: Thanks spiderko_2 that's what I was looking for!! Can you be contacted directly in case of other Access 2010 related questions?

Comment: Please feel free to ask questions